# WebSocket with free RDMBS (PostgreSQL, SQLite, etc) and without JavaScript ecosystem

Tags: postgresql, websocket, rdbms

I'm searching a simple implementation to push changes from a free relational database (PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite, etc.) to clients' browsers via [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or [WebPush](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-webpush-protocol-05).
I want to avoid all the server-side JavaScript ecosystem (Node.js, npm & cie) and the NoSQL databases.
All must be hosted in the servers of my company, I can't use third-party services.

I found these interesting solutions :

- http://initd.org/psycopg/articles/2010/12/01/postgresql-notifications-psycopg2-eventlet/ [with Python]
- https://gist.github.com/drocco007/6e44ac1a581546c16e67 [the same one slightly improved]
- https://coussej.github.io/2015/09/15/Listening-to-generic-JSON-notifications-from-PostgreSQL-in-Go/ [with Go]

Do you know other ways to get this done?
Is PostgreSQL the more suitable free RDBMS to do this?
Can it be accomplished with a SQLite database?
Can Apache or NGinx abilities be used to achieve this?

Comment: I updated my answer; I made a project called postgrest2websocket that could be interesting for you.

Answer (score 4):

**Update 01/23/17: I wrote an application called postgresql2websocket** in order to send PostgreSQL notifications over websockets using Python 3 with asyncio + aiohttp + asyncpg https://github.com/frafra/postgresql2websocket; you could combine it with [PostgREST](https://github.com/begriffs/postgrest) in order to have both standard REST APIs and realtime updates using WebSockets.

As far I know, there is no HTTP server extension for using SQL databases with Websockets without anything in the middle.

You can use Python on the server side, like this: [Real Time Web Apps with (just) Python and Postgres](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/3dgtjt/real_time_web_apps_with_just_python_and_postgres/). I think it could be improved thanks to [aiopg](https://aiopg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). If you don't need Websockets, you can just use [ngx_postgres](http://labs.frickle.com/nginx_ngx_postgres/).

If you like Django, [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) will be [probably included in Django 1.10](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2016/3/17/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django) (Redis/in-memory/... layer for channels and SQL backend).

You could use SQLite, but bear in mind that you have to implement a separate server side publish/subscribe mechanism (like Django channel does), because SQLite doesn't have one.

If you're just interested in pub/sub over Websockets, you could use [Webdis](http://webd.is/) (Redis-based solution): it would be probably lighter than a full SQL database.